# How to copy common elements in two arrays into a new array without using numpy

Tags: python, arrays

Can we get common elements in two arrays with loops and if condition?

```py
#copy the members of 1st array that are present 2nd array to 3rd array
import array as ar
import numpy as np
a1=ar.array('i',range(10))
a2=ar.array('i',[2,3,5,8,9,11,12])
​
​
a3=np.intersect1d(a1, a2)
​
print(a3)
type(a3)

#output

[2 3 5 8 9]
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, `a3 = set(a1) & set(a2)`.

Comment: Your question says "without using Numpy", yet your example code is full of Numpy. Can you state the example without Numpy first?

Comment: @AKX is right. If order matters, yes you can loop through each element of an array

Comment: @AKX thanks. That helped. Here's final code

```python

#copy the members of 1st array that are present 2nd array to 3rd array
import array as ar
import numpy as np
a1=ar.array('i',range(10))
a2=ar.array('i',[2,3,5,8,9,12,13,15])
a3=ar.array(a1.typecode,(set(a1)&set(a2)))
print(a3)

#output
array('i', [2, 3, 5, 8, 9])

```

Answer (score 0):

Python list comprehension is a powerful thing:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [3, 5, 4, 6]

c = [ x for x in a if x in b]

print(c)
# Output: [3, 4]
```

Comment: But this is list right! How can I implement it on arrays?

Comment: Python does not have arrays, only lists. Arrays are exclusive to numpy and you asked for it to be done without numpy

Comment: a3=ar.array(a1.typecode,(set(a1)&set(a2)))

Worked fine for me (:

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.
Lets take two arrays arr1 and arr2 and an empty array arr3.

```
arr1 = [i for i in range(1, 20)]
arr2 = [i for i in range(15, 25)]
arr3 = []
```

The conventional way would be to loop through the elements followed by an if statement that would check if the element is on the second array and append the element to the third array if the condition is satisfied.

```
arr3 = [i for i in arr1 if i in arr2]
```

Or you could convert the arrays into set and use intersection and convert them back.

```
arr3 = list(set(arr1).intersection(set(arr2)))
```

Comment: These are lists. Same is not working for arrays. Kindly clarify.

Comment: Python does not have built-in support for Arrays, but Python Lists can be used instead. You may know more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of set operators, I was able to get common elements in 2 arrays and returned to 3rd array.

```py
#copy the members of 1st array that are present 2nd array to 3rd array
import array as ar
a1=ar.array('i',range(10))
a2=ar.array('i',[2,3,5,8,9,12,13,15])
a3=ar.array(a1.typecode,(set(a1)&set(a2)))
print(a3)
type(a3)


#output
array('i', [2, 3, 5, 8, 9])
array.array

``
```